# OptaPlanner (Benchmark): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: scoreDirectorFactory lacks a configuration /scoreClass doesn't follow the correct pattern

Tags: xml, kotlin, optaplanner, illegalargumentexception

Hello I have a problem with the benchmark function of OptaPlanner. (The normal solver is working well)

So far: I have implemented it, that he starts the warm up phase, please see following code:
(the variable "unsolved" is the result of my PlanningSolution)

```
    val outputFileNameXML:String = "src/main/resources/benchmark/pgegpBenchmarkConfig.xml"
    val outputFileXML: File = File(outputFileNameXML)
    val benchmarkFactory: PlannerBenchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlFile(outputFileXML)

    val benchmark: PlannerBenchmark = benchmarkFactory.buildPlannerBenchmark(unsolved)
    benchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser()
```

Sadly, when I start it keeps displaying the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scoreDirectorFactory lacks a configuration for an easyScoreCalculatorClass, a constraintProviderClass, an incrementalScoreCalculatorClass or a droolsScoreDirectorFactory.
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.decideMultipleScoreDirectorFactories(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:124)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryFactory.java:68)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:116)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:83)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:99)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:35)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also it results with this error message, which I think could be connected to the first one:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.optaplanner.benchmark.api.PlannerBenchmarkException: Benchmarking failed: failureCount (1). The exception of the firstFailureSingleBenchmarkRunner (Problem_0_First Fit_0) is chained.
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkingEnded(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:325)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmark(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:100)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:423)
at pgegp.MainBenchmarkKt.main(mainBenchmark.kt:76)
at pgegp.MainBenchmarkKt.main(mainBenchmark.kt)
```

I think OptaPlanner can't use my constraintProviderclass. So I tried to add it in the xml in the scoreDirectoryFactory section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plannerBenchmark>
    <benchmarkDirectory>local/data/resolved/pgegpBenchmark</benchmarkDirectory>
    <parallelBenchmarkCount>AUTO</parallelBenchmarkCount>
    <warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>30</warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>

    <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
        <problemBenchmarks>
            <writeOutputSolutionEnabled>true</writeOutputSolutionEnabled>
            <problemStatisticType>BEST_SCORE</problemStatisticType>
        </problemBenchmarks>
        <solver>
            <solutionClass>pgegp.groupAssignment.domain.GroupAssignmentSolution</solutionClass>
            <entityClass>pgegp.groupAssignment.domain.GroupAssignment</entityClass>
            <scoreDirectorFactory>
                <constraintProviderClass>src.main.kotlin.pgegp.groupAssignment.solver.GroupAssignmentConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
                <scoreDefinitionType>SIMPLE</scoreDefinitionType>
                <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
            </scoreDirectorFactory>
            <terminiation>
                <minutesSpentLimit>1</minutesSpentLimit>
            </terminiation>
        </solver>
    </inheritedSolverBenchmark>
 <solverBenchmark>
     
        <name>First Fit</name>
        <solver>
            <constructionHeuristic>
                <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
            </constructionHeuristic>
        </solver>
  </solverBenchmark>
```

// EDIT (scoreClass doesn't follow the correct pattern)

OK I managed to find the problem. The pathname of ConstraintProviderclass was wrong and had to be "pgegp.groupAssignment.solver.GroupAssignmentConstraintProvider" (thank you very much Lukáš Petrovický).

Now it looks like it works and starts do the job. But sadly after a while it stops and shows me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scoreString (-225hard/-10295soft) for the scoreClass (GroupAssignmentScore) doesn't follow the correct pattern (999hard): the suffixedScoreToken (-225hard) does not end with levelSuffix (init).
at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.AbstractScore.parseScoreTokens(AbstractScore.java:49)
at pgegp.groupAssignment.solver.GroupAssignmentScore.access$parseScoreTokens$s-1211083920(GroupAssignmentScore.kt:9)
at pgegp.groupAssignment.solver.GroupAssignmentScore$Companion.parseScore(GroupAssignmentScore.kt:19)
at pgegp.groupAssignment.solver.GroupAssignmentScoreDefinition.parseScore(GroupAssignmentScoreDefinition.kt:33)
at pgegp.groupAssignment.solver.GroupAssignmentScoreDefinition.parseScore(GroupAssignmentScoreDefinition.kt:12)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.statistic.bestscore.BestScoreSubSingleStatistic.createPointFromCsvLine(BestScoreSubSingleStatistic.java:75)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.statistic.bestscore.BestScoreSubSingleStatistic.createPointFromCsvLine(BestScoreSubSingleStatistic.java:29)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.statistic.SubSingleStatistic.readCsvStatisticFile(SubSingleStatistic.java:183)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.statistic.SubSingleStatistic.unhibernatePointList(SubSingleStatistic.java:199)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.report.BenchmarkReport.writeReport(BenchmarkReport.java:267)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkingEnded(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:310)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmark(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:100)
at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkAndShowReportInBrowser(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:423)
at pgegp.MainBenchmarkKt.main(mainBenchmark.kt:128)
at pgegp.MainBenchmarkKt.main(mainBenchmark.kt)
```

I'm not sure why it deploys this message.

But sadly it doesn't work and I don't know what to do.

// EndEdit

Thank you very much!
Michael

Comment: Might the first error have something to do with the fact that, while the entity and solution are in package pgegp.*, the constraint provider class is in src.main.kotlin.pgegp.*? Looks to me like the "src.main.kotlin" shouldn't be there. That said, in that case, I would expect the exception to be different than it is. Mind sharing a simplified source code in a repo somewhere that I could run?

Comment: Thanks Lukáš, that helped. I added some informations down, because sadly more problems appeared.

Comment: I'd argue the second problem is a separate question. That looks like a really weird error - an impossible state. Do you have a reproducer? Our kotlin quickstart will soon get a benchmarker too, after this PR is polished and merged https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/pull/111/files

Comment: From what I'm seeing, michaelm uses a custom score implementation. Even though that is possible, it is certainly undocumented and I would like to understand the purpose for it.

Comment: Finally I was able to fix the problem. I had to change from the own Score Implementation to HardSoftScore. My colleague implemented that custom score to test it. He said he implemented it exactly like HardSoftScore. But it looks like benchmark doesn't take own Score implementations. Because there are very weird scores which don't appear like that in the actual "normal" solving case. Thank you very much again for your help!